Why does Jest use .[jt]s?(x) instead of .[jt]sx? in the default testMatch configuration?
In the Jest documentation, the default value for the testMatch configuration option is [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]. Since we want to match file extensions like .js, .jsx, .ts, and .tsx, why is it not .[jt]sx??
There are two places I don't quite understand:

The character 's' must appear.
Why is 'x' placed in a group?

I did the following test on regex101.com, and it seems that .[jt]s?(x) does not match as expected:



Ask the author of this PR https://github.com/jestjs/jest/pull/2359

These strings are globs, NOT regular expressions.  A regular expression engine would completely misinterpret them: for example, the ?(x) you see here is a "match zero or one" operation, that would be written x? in a regex.

"The glob patterns Jest uses... See the micromatch package for details of the patterns you can specify. See also testRegex..."

It's because testMatch is interpreted as an extended glob expression, not a regular expression. Matching is done with the micromatch library.
In particular, the extended glob syntax ?(pattern) is equivalent to the regular expression (pattern)?. So in the default testMatch value, [jt]s?(x) has s, a required s, and ?(x), an optional x.
Compare with the testRegex option, which is a regular expression. Its default value is (/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$, which is more like what you were expecting. In this pattern the character s is required and the x? makes x optional in this pattern.
